# salesforce email API

Tags: community

I'm looking into using salesforce for a simple email form on my webpage. User types their name and email into form, form connects to my node server. Node Server validates fields connects to salesforce endpoint to send mail to a specified email address.  I've looked into using AWS SES which looks like the way to go using there sdk for ses.sendMail() transfer.

Wanted to know if salesforce has something similar to SES where it has a SDK or API where I can do the same using node.js ? Or is sticking to mailgun or AWS the better and easier solution ?

Comment: Do you want Salesforce to manage Leads or contact details coming in from your website (i.e., act as a CRM)? If all you want is to send email, a purpose-built solution for that use case is probably going to be superior.

Comment: Don't need to use it as a CRM but might be nice to interact with salesforce tools down the line. Sorry didn't understand your last comment. "A purpose-built solution" do you mean AWS SES been the purpose built solution as opposed to salesforce ?